# How to add a text box with a vertical scroll bar and to a tkinter frame containing an accept and a decline button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter and i want to create a a license form that is accepted or declined. What is the most correct way of doing this ?...Create a Frame, and add one Tk() root with a Text(root) containing all the text inside and another Tk() below root as root2 with two buttons one labelled as accept and one as declined? or is there another way i am missing ?? thanks.

Comment: You should never create more than a single instance of `Tk`. Beyond that, there are at least three different ways to arrange widgets, using `pack`, `place`, and `grid`, and you can find documentation for all of those. If you need specific help, please show what you've tried.

Comment: I just solved it thanks...should i post the answer to receive points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *


texteula= '''END USER LICENSE AGREEMENT...etc etc'''

# define master
Eula = Tk()
Eula.title('Licence Agreement')

# Vertical (y) Scroll Bar
scroll = Scrollbar(Eula)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# Text Widget
eula = Text(Eula, wrap=NONE, yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
eula.insert("1.0", texteula)
eula.pack()
button= Button(Eula,text='Accept',command=Eula.destroy)
button.pack(side=LEFT)
button2= Button(Eula,text='Decline')
button2.pack(side=RIGHT)

# Configure the scrollbars
scroll.config(command=eula.yview)
mainloop()
```